# Securing URL using User Roles and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, user-roles

I have multiple User Roles in my Java application.
Here is my code:

```
private String userAccess[] = new String[]{"/dashboard/**"};
private String dataAccess[] = new String[]{"/dashboard/**", "/data/**"};
private String adminAccess[] = new String[]{"/dashboard/**", "/data/**", "/admin/**"};

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(publicResources).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(userAccess).hasRole("USER").anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers(dataAccess).hasRole("DATA").anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers(adminAccess).hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Error:

> 2019-12-18T12:00:34.059+0000 DEBUG Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /dashboard; Attributes: hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
>   2019-12-18T12:00:34.059+0000 DEBUG Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@62aad9e7: Principal: userdetails.CustomUserDetails@2228ff0d; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_DATA
>   2019-12-18T12:00:34.059+0000 DEBUG Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6925373, returned: -1
>   2019-12-18T12:00:34.062+0000 DEBUG Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
>   org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

Sorry, cannot seem to get the Exception showing in the "code" tag here :(

The problem now is when I logon with ADMIN all works 100%. But when I logon with USER or DATA, then I get an exception saying that I tried to access and unauthorised page.

So what is happening is that it loads the URL access for user DATA, but when the last line executes, it changes the /dashboard URL to have ADMIN access. My Role is still DATA role and thus don't have access to the /dashboard URL.

So it seems like the last line is overwriting the others. Looking at the URL privileges again, if I remove "/dashboard", then I will get the same issue when it comes to the "/data" URL.

Is there a better way of doing this or maybe a way for me to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if not repeat an endpoint for role

```
private String userAccess[] = new String[]{"/dashboard/**"};
    private String dataAccess[] = new String[]{"/data/**"};
    private String adminAccess[] = new String[]{"/admin/**"};

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(publicResources).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(userAccess).hasAnyRole("USER", "DATA", "ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers(dataAccess).hasAnyRole("DATA", "ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers(adminAccess).hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

Comment: There should be a single `anyRequest().authenticated()` and it should be last.

Answer (score 0):

The order of antMatchers is important.

More specific ones should go first. Least specific one should be last.

Reorder the antMatchers to be as follows:

```
.antMatchers(userAccess).hasRole("USER").anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers(dataAccess).hasRole("DATA").anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers(adminAccess).hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers(publicResources).permitAll()
```

I am assuming user is more specific than data.

Comment: True, because you are not fully understanding the matchers. The ordering is important and the first one to match wins. So the `/dashboard/**` always matches the user, it won't fall through.

Answer (score -1):

Strange authorization ... You need to change the logic.
In your config is written: `publicResources` permitAll AND matcher `userAccess` has role USER AND any requests authenticated AND matcher `dataAccess` has role DATA AND any requests authenticated AND ... (multiple definitions of anyRequest)

Comment: You are not providing any answer or solution here?